# How do I increase the "Available Today's Daily Quota" for AppJetty's "Language Translator For Magento 2"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, magento2, google-translation-api, magento2-extensions

I am working on a Magento 2 (specifically version 2.4.2) e-commerce website. I downloaded an extension called [Language Translator For Magento 2](https://www.appjetty.com/magento2-language-translator.htm) from AppJetty. I am unable to translate the site and I believe it is due to the configuration ["Available Today's Daily Quota: 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFkDI.png). I need help increasing the quota.

On the [Google Cloud site](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/translate.googleapis.com/), I see quotas but none of them are "1". I attempted to discuss with the AppJetty team over the phone, but that was unsuccessful.